# CFReadStreamRef vs. NSInputStream *

Tags: objective-c, ios, stream, nsstream, cfstream

The difference between `NSInputStream *` and `CFReadStreamRef` seems to be that the first one is an objective C object, while the second one is a native struct. Nevertheless, they are toll-free bridged.

I want to implement a program based on network streams.

- [[NSStream getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) produces `NSInputStream *` and `NSOutputStream *`. However, on iOS, this method is not available.

  Therefore, [CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html) has to be used on iOS.

  ```
  CFReadStreamRef readStream;
  CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
  CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(
                   kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readStream, &writeStream);
  NSInputStream *read = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
  NSOutputStream *write = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
  ```
- When setting stream properties, not all properties are available when `NSInputStream *` is used. Especially the `kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket` would be interesting to ensure that the socket is also closed when the corresponding stream is closed.

  Do I have to convert the `NSInputStream *` to a `CFReadStreamRef` to set this property, and then revert the conversion, to set such a property?
- ...

The `NSInputStream *` seems to have multiple disadvantages. Is its only advantage really that I can provide an own subclass of it, while I cannot do so in the `CFReadStreamRef` case? When should which method be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, most Foundation/CoreFoundation toll-free bridged classes are also similar in terms of behavior. But you're right, this is not the case for `NSInputStream *` and `CFReadStreamRef`. Apple's [Setting Up Socket Streams](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html) guide only explains what you describe. And even when using the latest initializers (like `inputStreamWithURL:` available in 10.6), it still doesn't work when `url` is remote (eg. `http://...`).

The main advantage I see to continue using `NSInputStream` is a better integration within an Objective-C application. At any time, you can try to change the property of your `NSInputStream *` object (*read*) like this:

```
if (!CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)read,
                              kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
                              kCFBooleanTrue))
     failure("property change not accepted");
```

As an alternative to all of this, I would suggest to take a look at the `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` objects described in [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).